# If $X = X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_n$ is shellable, then is $(X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_k)\cap X_{k+1}$ shellable?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry, simplicial-complexes

Let $X = X_1 \cup \cdots X_n$ be a [shellable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelling_(topology)) complex, where the $X_i$ are the maximal faces, in the shelling order.

**Question 1:**
Let $0 \leq k \leq n-1$. Then is $(X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_k) \cap X_{k+1}$ shellable?

I want to say the answer is *yes*, but I can't find this in print anywhere, and I'm not sure.

**Question 2:** Same question, but for chain-lexicographic shellability.

Comment: The given intersection is a pure complex of codimension 1 of simplex $X_{k+1}$ hence it must be shellable.

Comment: @WlodAA Ah, thank you! I see now that the question is much simpler than I had appreciated. By definition of shellability, $(X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_k) \cap X_{k+1} \subseteq X_{k+1} = \Delta^d$ is the union of some nonempty subset of the codimension-1 faces $\Delta^{d-1}$. To see that this is shellable (in any ordering), it suffices to observe that if $Y,Z \subseteq \Delta^d$ are any two codimension-1 faces, then $Y \cap Z$ is a simplex of dimension $d-2$. If you were to write this as answer, I would gladly accept it!

Comment: Tim, thank you. Sometimes one gets some kind of a block, looks at something and doesn't see it (e.g. that a simplex is a **simplex**), it happens (to me too, of course). I feel that I shouldn't call my comment an Answer. I hope that now you can go forward in your research smoothly for a while. Best regards.

Comment: For simplicial complexes the question is uninteresting, but for polyhedral complexes it makes more sense. The answer boils down to how one *defines* shellability. Usually the condition in Question1 is part of the definition. E.g., see Definition 2.3  at https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/math/groups/discgeom/ziegler/Preprintfiles/046PREPRINT.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *yes*, as indicated in the comments. Thanks to WlodAA!